# Real-time data changes using two-way binding for each instance in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, object, swiftui, instance, two-way-binding

I would like to create instances of Circle() nodes where the user can tap and drag them around on the screen. Each time a Circle() node is pulled from its starting position a new one is created in its place, allowing the user to create as many as they want.

I then want to have this real-time changing data of the screen position for each of the instances created, yet in different views of my choosing, so I may use it for further graphics and effects.

How can I access each individual instance’s real-time screen position data from a different view?

Here is the child view I want to create instances of, accessing the currentPosition variable:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Child: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: DataBridge
    @Binding var stateBinding: CGSize
    
    @State var isInitalDrag = true
    @State var isOnce = true
    
    @State var currentPosition: CGSize = .zero
    @State var newPosition: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .offset(self.currentPosition)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        
                        if self.isInitalDrag && self.isOnce {
                            
                            // Call function in ContentView here:
                            
                            self.isOnce = false
                        }
                        
                        self.currentPosition = CGSize(
                            width: CGFloat(value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width),
                            height: CGFloat(value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)
                        )
                        
                        self.stateBinding = self.currentPosition
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        self.newPosition = self.currentPosition
                        
                        self.isOnce = true
                        self.isInitalDrag = false
                    }
            )
    }
}

struct Child_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Child(stateBinding: .constant(.zero))
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only access it when you have a reference to the circle view. But when you have a reference, you can just access `currentPosition`, as it is not marked as private. `var myCircle = Circle(); myCircle.currentPosition()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach we had conversation about is you can store your data in an `EnviornmentObject` and create an object to store it's properties and the view will take a binding and the view's job is to update the object's properties. In your case this view is `ChildView`. So because I know your code from previous posts I will include it here.

I have renamed `Child` to `ChildView` because really it's job is just to show the circle and update it, but additionally I have created a model called `Child` which is what we want to present.

`Child.swift`

```
import SwiftUI

struct Child: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var location: CGSize

    init(location: CGSize = .zero) {
        self.location = location
    }
}
```

It's a very simple declaration, we have specified a `location` and an `ID` to be able to identify it.

then I changed `ChildView` to the following

`ChildView.swift`

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var child: Child
    var onDragged = {}
    
    @State private var isInitalDrag = true
    @State private var isOnce = true
    @State private var currentPosition: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var newPosition: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .offset(self.currentPosition)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        if self.isInitalDrag && self.isOnce {
                            self.onDragged()
                            self.isOnce = false
                        }
                        
                        self.currentPosition = CGSize(
                            width: CGFloat(value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width),
                            height: CGFloat(value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)
                        )
                        
                        self.child.location = self.currentPosition
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        self.newPosition = self.currentPosition
                        self.isOnce = true
                        self.isInitalDrag = false
                    }
            )
            .onAppear {
                  // Pay attention whenever the circle view appears we update it's currentPosition and newPosition to be the child's location
                  self.currentPosition = self.child.location
                  self.newPosition = self.child.location
            }
    }
    
    func onDragged(_ callaback: @escaping () -> ()) -> some View {
        ChildView(child: self.$child, onDragged: callaback)
    }
}
```

So as you can see I have removed some of the previous code as it will be irrelevant. The goal is that each `ChildView` will present 1 `Child` object for us; hence, our `ChildView` includes a binding property called `child`. I have also changed the rest of our properties to be `private` as there is really 0 reason to share these states with different views.

Also notice whenever there is a drag I change the `child` object's location property. This is very important because now whenever we reference this child in any view it will have the same location.

Additionally, note I have removed `@EnvironmentObject` from the `ChildView` as it really doesn't need to change our `environment` instead it only announces that it is being dragged and whichever view is calling it can do different actions when dragging, maybe one wants to create new child but the other wants to change a color. So it's best practice to separate these for scalability. think of `ChildView` as a component than a real full blown view.

I then changed our `EnvironmentObject` to be as follows

`AppState.swift` (I think you called it `DataBridge` I was lazy to change the name :D)

```
class AppState : ObservableObject {
    @Published var childInstances: [Child] = []
    
    init() {
        self.createNewChild()
    }
    
    func createNewChild() {
        let child = Child()
        self.childInstances.append(child)
    }
}
```

It's much simpler than the previous code, as it really has only an array of `Child` and pay very close attention, its an array of the object `Child` not the view `ChildView` like you had before! it also includes a function to create a new child object whenever it's called.

Finally here is your `ContentView`

`ContentView.swift`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(self.appState.childInstances.enumerated().map({$0}), id:\.element.id) { index, child in
                ChildView(child: self.$appState.childInstances[index])
                    .onDragged {
                        self.appState.createNewChild()
                    }
            }

            VStack {
                ForEach(self.appState.childInstances, id: \.self.id) { child in
                    Text("y: \(child.location.height) : x: \(child.location.width)")
                }
            }
            .offset(y: -250)
        }
    }
}
```

In this file all we are doing is enumerating through our child instances (again the objects not the views) and for each child we are creating a new view and passing it the `child` object as a `Binding` so whenever the `ChildView` makes changes it will actually change the original `Child` object. Also note that I handle `.onDragged` in this view since it's a real view that controls the app and not a partial component that describes an object.

I apologize if it's long but I tried to explain everything so it won't be confusing. This is a scalable approach because now your `Child` can have multiple properties, maybe each child can have it's own random color instead of blue? that can be now possible by creating a new property in `Child` model called `color` and then you reference it in your `ChildView`.

This architecture now also allows you to for example in a different view lets call it `ChangeColorView.swift` to reference any child from our `AppState.childInstances` and then change its color when the location = a different circle's location then set their colors to be the same, etc.... really the sky is the limit. This is known as OOP (Object Oriented Programming).

Let me know if I can help any further.

Comment: Thank you so much @Muhand! You really helped me out here! This is exactly what I'm looking for. Now I can scale up and use the changing Child location data anywhere because of the @EnvironmentObject class. I like how you separated the data out to work with more. Yes, I can see why those properties are marked private, why the child's location property is changed when a drag happens, and why you have a separate model for child and append that instead of the ChildView. I understand most of the parts separately. It's not too long. I just need to study it more as a whole and see the flow of it all.

Comment: you are obviously a skilled programmer. I want to be able to solve problems and know how to implement my code the way you do. You do it with ease too... You handed me a very nice fish here. How do I become a fisherman like you, so to speak? You said this is OOP, yet the Child class you called it a model. Is this also MVVM? If I study the different architectures like MVC, MVVM, OOP do you think I can implement code like you do? I ask because right now I couldn't come up with the way you did this... I understand Swift in components, but as a whole I don't know if I'm coding correctly.

Comment: My pleasure. Just take your time studying the code and I am 100% sure you will get it all. It's not that complicated just like you have noted in your comment. I would like to point out I have been programming for a very long time over 14 years, you won't learn it overnight. It will take time and patience, and you seem to be a very bright person so I don't suspect it taking 14 years. The most important advice I can give you is practice, practice, practice and practice. There is no wrong way of doing things (there is clean and best practices) but starting out, your goal is to get things to work.

Comment: and not to worry about clean code or architecture yet. This can always come with refactoring. Sometimes I rewrite the same application 5~7 times and every time I fix something in it that I didn't like before and this will develop knowledge for you. I am overly obsessed with developing clean, scalable systems hence I am a backend engineer. There is a big difference between a programmer and an engineer, what you want to learn is engineering and engineering really likes practice and understanding different stacks, data structures and architecture, I am an engineer.

Comment: So you are confusing the concept of OOP, MVC and MVVM. OOP is very different from MVC and MVVM, they are not comparable. OOP is a way of programming or in better terms its an architecture that can be compared to functional and procedural programming. While MVC and MVVM are design patterns that implement OOP. In other words everything you write in swift is actually meant to be OOP architecture but with `UIkit` they pushed for `MVC` while in `SwiftUI` they are pushing for `MVVM` design pattern. When I called `Child` a model that's because it's a model that can get instantiated and creates an...

Comment: object. That's the `Object` part in `OOP`, now everything else is oriented around this one object, such as developing a view that displays it and then developing a controller to control the view. The naming convention it really depends on your design pattern. What matters in `OOP` is that you have an object which includes properties and includes it's own functions. For example, you can define a `keyboard` object that includes a property such as an array of `key` but `key` is another object it self which has property such as `hex` and `value`  then you can have a `KeyboardView` which will...

Comment: draw the keyboard with all the keys on it. `Keyboard` can also have functions such as `Keypressed`, etc... We have just created an `Architecture` to our `Keyboard` software design. Now we as engineers would hand it over to programmers who will convert this paper, UML design into a software/app/etc... using any language and any design pattern such as  `MVVM` in `SwiftUI` but the infrastructure was developed in `OOP` architecture. This is obviously a very short description of OOP, at the end of the day these are comments and we don't want to pollute this post. You can connect with me...

Comment: on linkedin if you need any help, I am more than happy to help you or even have further discussion around `OOP` and design patterns. My linkedin is https://www.linkedin.com/public-profile/in/muhandjumah or if you prefer posting questions and then drop a link in one of the comments and I will be happy to assist you further. Just remember to keep practicing and don't get hang up on clean code and architecture, get it to work first! Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible approach (scratchy, only important code shown) - the data from subviews into parent view can be passed via view preferences.

So we have preference key to store dictionary of child id as key and its position as value, parent view creates child with id, child stores own position in preferences, parent reads positions on preference change.

```
struct ViewPositionsKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue = [Int: CGSize]()
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value.merge(nextValue(), uniquingKeysWith: { $1 })
    }
}

struct Child: View {

    let id: Int
    @State var currentPosition: CGSize = .zero

    // ... other code

    var body: some View {
        Circle()

               // ... other code
        )
        .preference(key: ViewPositionsKey.self, value: [id: currentPosition])
    }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack { // example fo container
           
            // your child views here

        }
        .onPreferenceChange(ViewPositionsKey.self) { value in
            // value is [childId: Position] - do anything needed
        }
    }
}
```