# SwiftUI calling delegate in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

This is the first time I am working with SwiftUI, and I have searched for this problem but did not find any working solution, so I would appreciate all help I can get.

I have a UIViewController, in which I present a SwiftUI View through UIHostingController. What I want to achieve is that when I press the button in my SwiftUI view, the action is going to trigger the delegate in UIViewController, alternatively, trigger a function in UIViewController and then from that function trigger the delegate.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

public var delegate: MyViewControllerDelegate?
let facialView = UIHostingController(rootView: FacialTutorial())

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

addChild(facialView)
view.addSubview(facialView.view)
setupConstraints()

}

extension MyViewController {

@objc private func buttonPressed() {

delegate?.buttonPressed()

}

}


}
```

And in my SwiftUI view FacialTutorial

```
struct FacialTutorial: View {

var body: some View {

        VStack() {
          Button {
              // I want to call delegate?.buttonPressed() action here
          } label: {
              Text("Press button")
          }
        
      }

}


}
```

**EDIT**

Okay to be more clear, my ViewController is configuring the page differently for a number of cases. So in practice, I do not initiate the SwiftUI view from viewWillAppear. Rather this is how I do

```
public var delegate: MyViewControllerDelegate?
let facialView = UIHostingController(rootView: FacialTutorial())


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    addChild(facialView)
    configureSubviews()
}



private func configureForInstructionMode() {

  view.addSubview(facialUIView.view)
  setupConstraints()
}
```

I must have it this way because I need to configure the view differently depending on which mode I am going to configure for. When I declare the facialView inside the viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, I cannot access the instance in configureForInstructionMode(), or it's value is nil..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - Button - How to pass a function request to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59861199/swiftui-button-how-to-pass-a-function-request-to-parent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to pass a reference to your `MyViewController` instance through to `MyUIView` (Which should probably be `MyView` since it isn't a subclass of `UIView`) via its initialiser.  You could use a delegation pattern or you could pass a closure and then invoke the delegate method from the closure.  The second way is more "Swifty".

(I have moved the code to `viewDidLoad` since if you have it in `viewWillAppear` the view may be added multiple times if the view controller appears and disappears and appears again)

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    public var delegate: MyViewControllerDelegate? {
        
    weak var myView: UIHostingController<MyUIView>!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myView = UIHostingController(rootView: MyUIView(buttonHandler: { [weak self] in
                self?.delegate?.buttonPressed()
            }))
        self.myView = myView
        view.addSubview(myView.view)
        setupConstraints()
    }
}
```

Then, in your SwiftUI view you can declare a property to hold the closure and invoke that closure in your button

```
struct MyUIView: View {
    
    var buttonHandler: (()->Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Button {
                buttonHandler?()
            } label: {
                Text("Press button")
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually it worked now! Thanks for the help. By the way, do you know how I can pass some parameters to the SwiftUI View when I initiate it? So that I can pass in which mode I want to configure for, and then in my SwiftUI I can adapt the view for the specific mode?

Comment: The same as I did when I passed the closure - Declare a property in your `MyUIView` and then pass the value via the initialiser.

Comment: Okay, I did that and it also worked. However I noticed that I want to only show the SwiftUI view when in certain modes, and in other modes not initiate the SwiftUI view and just go with the regular ViewController. That's why I had moved the initiating of SwiftUI into a specific function, so that when the specific mode is true then only then the SwiftUI view is launched. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: You set the relevant properties of your view controller before the view is loaded and then you can test those properties in `viewDidLoad`. Exactly how depends on how you are getting to this view controller - segue, just showing or presenting it.. setting the view to `hidden` in `viewWillAppear` May also be an option.